# sticky left part with bottom limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, sticky

I have contact div and I made it sticky with bootstrap affix.

```
<div id="contactForm" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="400">
```

But how to limit it's bottom to next div top. Means, when it reaches "ticker-container" div top to stay as it is.(the news ticker)

how can i do it?

this is the page with the div:
http://www.sapbusinessone.co.il/he/company/about/main/

thanks

Comment: better create a snippet or fiddle

Comment: use `data-offeset-bottom="x"` where `x` is number of pixel

Answer (score 0):

add this to your html page at the end:

```
<script>
    $('#contactForm').affix({
      offset: {
        bottom: ($('#SiteFooterContainer').outerHeight(true)+40)
      }
    });
</script>
```

For more information on this:
[EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/full/GgOzwX/)
[UNDERSTAND THE CODE](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/GgOzwX)